# Get pthread_create error 13 (permission) when trying to start mysql

Tags: mysql, linux

I am trying start a clean 5.6 mysql install on RedHat AWS box.  It hangs after printing the following in the logs.  It eventually dies:

```
mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
[Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
[Warning] Buffered warning: Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)
[Warning] Buffered warning: Changed limits: table_cache: 431 (requested 2000)
[Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
[Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
[Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
[Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
[Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
[Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
[Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
[Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
[Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
[Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Error: pthread_create returned 13
mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

It doesn't create a socket at all.  Here is the my.cnf:

```
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

# Recommended in standard MySQL setup
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ perror 13
OS error code  13:  Permission denied
```

Perhaps you weren't root when you installed?

```
[Warning] Buffered warning: Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)
```

That is caused by ulimit (in the OS) being only 1024.

Comment: I did yum install mysql-server mysql-client mysql common while I was root.   And I ran it while I was root using 'service mysqld start'

Comment: check all the directories mentioned in the paths in the messages -- all must be at least r-x for the "mysql" user.

Answer (score 0):

I also had InnoDB: Error: pthread_create returned 13 on starting mysql server on Centos 7.

Found this question, checked the permissions on the mysql folders but couldn't find any wrong permissions.

Updating mysql server to the newest version fixed everything for me.
(I am now on Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.23)